# Different class file templates per solution + project type

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, productivity-power-tools

Is there any way that I could create different templates for empty class file **per solution and per project type (project guid)**.

Eg.: in Solution A i want to add default usings, but in solution B i want to have other default usings. Also, for new solutions i want to use default VS settings.

I am aware i can change class template in Visual Studio, but then this settings is applied to **all** solutions and project types.

I am also aware I can create my own item template, but i rather override have this option on adding Class.

Also, is there a way to export this "settings file" and apply it to other environments.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the .zip files that contain the templates and rerun `devenv.exe /setup` each time you want to load a different set.

Or you can create your own project template and item templates and implement fancy logic in the [IWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) interface to transform the template in any way you want. You'd have to implement this yourself, there is no out of the box solution that does this right now. You could store the item templates as part of your solution I suppose.

Comment: I don't want to rerun with /setup parameter each time. I do switch between projects frequently.

Comment: Then you're out of options, unless you build your own templates and create a custom wizard by implementing the IWizard interface for it.